# Recursive TreeView does not retain structure when items added to underlying ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

Am building a recursive WPF TreeView out of this model:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Category1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category2 { get; set; }
}
```

So (badly named) Category1 is a collection of child categories and Category2 is the parent Category. This latter can be null if it's at the top level of the tree.

TreeView is being rendered like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Category1}">
            <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ViewContentsCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding}" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </Button>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Categories is an ObservableCollection so that it should update when users add or remove items from the collection via the UI. In terms of display, this all works as expected.

What I can't figure out is what happens when a user adds an item to the collection. Here's the code:

```
public void AddCategory()
{
    Category c = new Category { Description = "New Category",  Category2Id = SelectedCategory.CategoryId };
    Categories.Add(c);
    OnPropertyChanged("Categories"); //to refresh the UI
}
```

If you stick a breakpoint here and examine the Categories collection, it's as expected - the new item has slotted into the tree where it should, underneath its assigned ParentId. At the top level (i.e. items with null for Category2Id) there are the same number of items as before. But in the UI, this new item gets rendered as though it's at the top level instead of the correct place in the tree.

At first, I wondered if this was a peculiarity of working with the ObservableCollection directly, so I tried this:

```
public void AddCategory()
{
    List<Category> cats = Categories.ToList();
    Category c = new Category { Description = "New Category",  Category2Id = SelectedCategory.CategoryId };
    cats.Add(c);
    Categories = cats.ToObservableCollection();
}
```

Which I expected to have no effect but which, to my surprise, resulted in nothing happening at all - i.e. the new category doesn't appear in the UI at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that your data model is incorrect. It is more customary to have a `Category` class that contains properties including a collection of child `Category` items, eg. 2 levels; this level and the children level.  You will then need to populate your data model so that the children items exist in the parent's collections. This will then match the properties on the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`... bind the `Category1` collection property to the `ItemsSource` property.

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks for taking a look. I'm not sure I follow though: the Category class does include a collection of children as described. When I add the new item and look at the tree in Visual Studio, the child appears in the parent's collection. The binding works fine for purposes of display and navigation - it just goes wrong when adding a new category.

Comment: Your code did not originally bind to the correct property (perhaps just a typo)... either way, I think that you just need to notify the change to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Calling the `Add` method on a collection property will not alert the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface of any change... just manually call (your implementation of the interface method): `NotifyPropertyChanged("Categories");` at the end of your `AddCategory` method.

Comment: What happens if you assign the object reference to the parent instead of the foreign key? I think the tree understand about object references after all.

Comment: That's why I said that 'I think that your data model is incorrect'... you shouldn't have an ID links, but instead have a fully hierarchical model, where child objects actually exist inside the collections of parent items. Also, the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` doesn't work correctly with parents, so you should work with 'this' item and it's children, not it's parent.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `Add` method on a collection will not alert the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) of any change... just manually call (your implementation of the interface method)...

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("Categories");
```

... at the end of your `AddCategory` method to alert the interface to the fact that the `Categories` collection has changed.

Comment: Surely if it's a case of missing notifications the tree would not up date *at all* rather than just update wrongly? Besides, after the add, I'm re-assigning the property value ... i.e.Categories = cats.ToObservableCollection()?

Comment: (And sorry, yes, there were typos in the original post)